# DbUpdateException on DbContext in Autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac, sqlexception

I have a EF DbContext which I registered in my Autofac container:

```
builder.RegisterType<Data.Foobar>().As<IFoobarContext>().InstancePerDependency();
```

This object is being used in other objects which I also registered in my Autofac container:

```
builder.RegisterType<InteractionManager>().As<IInteractionManager>().SingleInstance();
```

Now I'm getting a error once in a while after updating the database:

> Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Message: The INSERT
>   statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ParticipantCode_Participant". The conflict occurred in database
>   "database", table
>   "dbo.Participant", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

After a IIS reset this error vanishes and the same action will run without any exceptions. I know for sure that the FK is correct.

After some research it looked like the dbcontext could be in an inconsistent state. I added the following to my Data.Foobar registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<Data.Foobar>().As<IFoobarContext>().OnActivating(x =>
    {
         x.Instance.Dispose();
         x.ReplaceInstance(new Data.Foobar());
    })
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

This does not work either.

It is a really strange issue with not much to go on so that is why I am asking all of you. Could it be that because my InteractionManager is a singleinstance, my dbcontext is also and the database state is not being updated correctly?

Comment: First things first... I've seen this error recently... and it was because the DBA was reindexing... ensure that's not the case.

Comment: Could you please show us the Participant and ParticipantCode types as well, especially the key properties and any foreign key properties?